# plist stored value is different while accessing in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, plist, ibeacon, clbeaconregion

I have maintained beacon information in plist and when I initialized the CLBeaconRegion, I am getting different Major and Minor values for the region. After doing NSLog I came to know that Major and Minor values holding in an NSString are giving me the correct values as in the plist and when I convert the values to CLBeaconMajorValue or CLBeaconMinorValue or NSInteger the values are different. I have changed both NSString and Number datatype in plist but with no luck. Why is this happening? Could you please help me to rectify this issue?

```
                NSUInteger major = (NSUInteger) [beaconInfo objectForKey:@"major"];
                NSUInteger minor = (NSUInteger)[beaconInfo objectForKey:@"minor"];

                NSLog(@"major : %ld, minor : %ld", major, minor);


                NSString *majorString =  [beaconInfo objectForKey:@"major"];
                NSString *minorString = [beaconInfo objectForKey:@"minor"];
                 NSLog(@"major : %@, minor : %@", majorString, minorString);
                NSLog(@"major : %hu, minor : %hu",  (CLBeaconMajorValue)majorString, (CLBeaconMinorValue) minorString);

                CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID: [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString: [beaconInfo objectForKey:@"uuid"]] major: (CLBeaconMajorValue) [beaconInfo objectForKey:@"major"] minor: (CLBeaconMinorValue) [beaconInfo objectForKey:@"minor"] identifier:@"com.test"];
                NSLog(@"%@", region);
```

The plist is

[image]

NSLog generated are

major : -5764607523034234861, minor : -5764607523034234861

major : 1, minor : 1

major : 19, minor : 19

CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'com.test', uuid:03672CE6-9272-48EA-BA54-0BF679217980, major:19, minor:19)

Comment: According to your screenshot: Use `NSUInteger major = [[beaconInfo objectForKey:@"major"] integerValue];` because `[beaconInfo objectForKey:@"major"]` is a `NSNumber` object. (same for minor). Not check that they are alls of the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your plist, the value is typed as `Number`, so the values are `NSNumber` when read.

So `[beaconInfo objectForKey:@"major"]` is a `NSNumber` object.

So you need to write `NSUInteger major = [(NSNumber *)[beaconInfo objectForKey:@"major"] integerValue];` which can be simplified with `NSUInteger major = [[beaconInfo objectForKey:@"major"] integerValue];`

Same for minor.

Just check that all the values major/minor in your .plist are of type Number.